using cookies from next/headers marks all pages as dynamic
When I am using cookies from "next/headers" it marks all pages as dynamic, this is not what I want my structure is like this in layout.tsx I have a child server component in which I want to read cookies this is ok it works but then when I build the app all pages are dynamic is there any other way to read cookies but other pages like home page, contact page to stay static as they are.
this is how I read cookie
const basketRecordId = cookies().get(COOKIES_ENUMS.BASKET_RECORD_ID)?.value;
and if comment this line of code then everything is ok.

You'd need to move your server component out of the root layout.tsx and use it only in pages (or groups of pages) that actually depend on cookies. For example, you can implement it in app/dashboard/layout.tsx. This way your home page would remain static, but all pages under the /dashboard would be dynamic.
